# Elasticsearch fuzzy query hit is more relevant than direct hit

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, relevance

I am having problems with fuzzy queries giving higher relavance to the fuzzy hit term than the direct match. I dont understand why - even after having rtfm.

1. Creating a new index

> curl -XPUT http://192.168.178.40:9200/test_test_test

2. Inserting to entries

> ```
> curl -XPUT http://192.168.178.40:9200/test_test_test/test/1 -d '{ "name": "nike" }'
>
> curl -XPUT http://192.168.178.40:9200/test_test_test/test/2 -d '{ "name": "bike" }'
> ```

3. Querying for search term "bike"

> curl -XPOST http://192.168.178.40:9200/test_test_test/test/_search -d
>   '{ "query": { "match": { "name": { "query": "bike", "fuzziness": "1" }
>   } } }' | jq

This gives a result with nike having higher relevance than bike. Why is that and how can this be fixed?

[image: result]

Comment: Using your example in 6.5.4, I was unable to get the same results - the `bike` document always returned a higher score.  Can you note what version you're using?
Additionally, can you post the output of `explain` for both documents?  E.g.:

GET test_test_test/test/1/_explain?format=yaml
{
  <same query body>
}

Comment: Its happening with ES 2.3.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with how scoring has changed since then - if you could run `explain` on both and post the results, it should shed some additional insight:

GET test_test_test/test/1/_explain?format=yaml { <same query body> } 
GET test_test_test/test/2/_explain?format=yaml { <same query body> }